# I am using simple cart js for my cart in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, actionmethod, simplecart

I am using simpleCart js for my ecommerce project in asp.net mvc. All is going well and items are stored in cart. Basically the cart is storing items in local storage of client browser. I have a anchor tag on which user will clik and go to check out page where i want to show all the cart products which is stored in local storage.
I cannot get local storage data in my action. Anybody any idea how it will be done?

Comment: you don't need to do anything on the back-end, just manipulate it in the onload of your page with js

Comment: <div class="simpleCart_items"></div>
this will show the cart data in a table. How to customize that table ?

Comment: I want this table in a c# list on server side

Comment: and where is the code?

Comment: Back to basics: If you want data _submitted_ to the server, then _submit_ it. Storing it in `localStorage` just does what it says. Server has no concept of it.